To use Sentry in Symfony
I am in no way able to pass on the errors to the sentry...
in .env:
SENTRY_DSN="https://example"

in config/bundles.php:

    Sentry\SentryBundle\SentryBundle::class => ['all' => true],

in config/packages/sentry.yaml:
sentry:
  dsn: '%env(SENTRY_DSN)%'
  options:
    traces_sample_rate: 1.0
    profiles_sample_rate: 1.0

test in src/Controller/SentryTestController:
class SentryTestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/sentry-test", name="sentry_test")
     */
    public function testLog()
    {
        try {
            throw new Exception('Test exception for Sentry');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            \Sentry\captureException($e);
            return new Response('Exception captured by Sentry');
        }
    }

}

here is some information about my version of sentry-symfony:
composer show sentry/sentry-symfony

name     : sentry/sentry-symfony

descrip. : Symfony integration for Sentry (http://getsentry.com)

keywords : errors, logging, sentry, symfony

versions : * 5.0.0

released : 2024-04-09, 1 month ago

I'm using the newest Symfony to date: 7.0 with PHP 8.2, my system is Linux.
I've already checked and the dsn key is in fact validated, as is my sentry account, so I don't know what else to do, I'm almost giving up on using the platform...

Are you using Monolog ? If so please check : https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/#monolog-integration and configure register_error_listener / register_error_handler
